# Optimizing SQL group by and join query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have two large tables of users and purchases (respectively 10^6 and 10^8 rows).
I'm using mySql to run the query here in the following, but it takes ages to compute!
What is the best way to speed up execution? Should I use index or split the query into two queries?

```
CREATE TABLE user(
uID INTEGER, 
countryCode varchar(2)
);

CREATE TABLE purchases(
uID INTEGER, 
productID INTEGER, 
price INTEGER
);

SELECT U.countryCode AS country, SUM(P.price) AS amount
FROM user U, purchases P
WHERE U.uid = P.uid
GROUP BY U.countryCode
ORDER BY U.countryCode ASC;
```

---

I guess the problem is in the Type:All. Explain gives me this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra  
1   SIMPLE  U   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    9653    Using temporary; Using filesort  
1   SIMPLE  P   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    97816   Using where; Using join buffer
```

Comment: Add an index on `countryCode` and then run `explain select ...` to see if you need any more indexes (`price` too).

Comment: How long are these country codes that need `TEXT` datatype?

Comment: just a couple of letters... and I just changed the TEXT in varchar(2)

Comment: Your tables needed indexes.  Read http://use-the-index-luke.com/ for a fine introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX USER_countryCode_uid ON user(countryCode,uid);

CREATE INDEX PURCHASES_uid_price ON purchases(uid,price);
```

EXPLAIN then improves:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: U
         type: index
possible_keys: USER_countryCode_uid
          key: USER_countryCode_uid
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10004
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: P
         type: ref
possible_keys: PURCHASES_uid_price
          key: PURCHASES_uid_price
      key_len: 5
          ref: test.U.uID
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
```

PS: You should define a primary key for every table, though this is not the issue for this particular query.

Comment: Very good, this is what I was looking for! Thanks Bill. I would definitely up vote this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

> CREATE INDEX countryCode_IDX ON USER(countryCode);

Use this Index in your query.

> SELECT U.countryCode AS Country, Sum(P.Price) AS Amount FROM USER U FORCE INDEX (countryCode_IDX) LEFT JOIN Purchases P ON U.uid = P.uid GROUP BY U.countryCode ORDER BY U.countryCode ASC;

Use the foreign key index for uid column.

Comment: There are no foreign keys in the OP's tables (or primary key either).

Comment: this is not working, the countryCode_IDX index is not giving speed up.